# How to filter nested sap.m.Lists with a SearchField?

Tags: sapui5

I created a list which has two more lists inside of it.
Here's the rough structure (working example at the end of the question):

```js
// Data structure
results: [{
  group: "1",
  children: [{
    group: "foo1",
    children: [{
      value1: "foo1.1",
      value2: "bar1.1"
    }, {
      value1: "foo1.2",
      value2: "bar1.2"
    }],
  }],
}]
// Element structure
List({
  items: {
    path: "/results",
    template: CustomListItem({
      content: List({
        path: "children",
        template: CustomListItem({
          content: List({
            path: "children",
            template: StandardListItem({
              title: "{value1}",
              info: "{value2}",
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Now I want to filter the items in the last lists and I don't understand how to do it.

For a single list I got it:

```js
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
  var sQuery = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
  var oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    filters: [
      new sap.ui.model.Filter("value1", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery),
      new sap.ui.model.Filter("value2", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)
    ],
    and: false
  });
  var oBinding = this.byId("list-id").getBinding("items");
  oBinding.filter(oFilter, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
}
```

But in my case the `value1` and `value2` arent directly in the `"list-id"` list, but two levels below.

Here's a link to the minimal example:
https://jsfiddle.net/54xzbvsp/

Comment: I had a similar problem (with a different framework though) and I performed the filtering directly on the original dataset with javascript & a bit of recursion. Keep in mind what type of result do you want to obtain... I mean, do you want to mantain the hierarchy or do you need only a "flat" result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment suggested as well, I couldn't find a solution using the `Filter` object, so I filtered the data manually and it worked like this:

```js
onSearch: function(oEvent) {
    let sQuery = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
    let originalModel = this.getView().getModel();
    let originalDataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalModel.oData));
    let filtered = originalDataCopy.results.filter(topGroup => {
      // Filter second level groups
      let filteredMidGroups = topGroup.children.filter(midGroup => {
        // Filter last Level
        let filteredSingleElements = midGroup.children.filter(singleElement => {
          let search = sQuery.toLowerCase();
          let valueFound = (
            singleElement.value1.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
            singleElement.value2.toLowerCase().includes(search)
          );
          return valueFound;
        });
        midGroup.children = filteredSingleElements;
        return (filteredSingleElements.length > 0);
      });
      topGroup.children = filteredMidGroups;
      return (filteredMidGroups.length > 0);
    });
    let oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
      results: filtered
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "filtered");
}
```

Here the full minimal working example: https://jsfiddle.net/kh1fep3z/2/

Answer (score 1):

It will not work with the standard filter on json model.

You should look into a tree if u have a 3 layer Hierarchie.

Comment: Thx for the info - I will try using a tree next time then, have never used it before :)